# c++ vector of vectors destruction

Tags: c++, vector, memory-management, destructor

hi I've `vector<vector<int> > matrix;` I initialize it by:

```
inline void resize(const UINT nrows, const UINT ncols, T val) {
vector<T> v_rows(ncols, val);
matrix.resize(nrows, v_rows);
}
```

now I'm concerned if I call resize again where the old ones go, do I have to call clear ? for the outer matrix ? or clear for each one matrix.at(i).clear(); or I don't need to do anything ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have to do anything as long a T manages it's own resources.  Which, if it doesn't, clear() isn't going to help.

Comment: T is going to be mostly numeric primitive type like int, double , float are those ok ?

Comment: Yep, in that case, resource management is automatic, since they just go on the stack.

Comment: Nothing contained by a standard container goes onto stack. It's more a matter of whether a type manages any resources and how (e.g. pointer's don't "manage" memory they point to).

Answer (score 2):

If you call `clear` (or a `resize` with smaller size) on a vector of anything, then all elements from that vector which need to be deleted have their destructors called and their memory is released.

If you have a vector of vectors, then each inner vector's destructor will clean up its resources properly. When a row-vector or column-vector is destroyed, it cleans up after itself automatically.

Comment: Interestingly enough, wikipedia disagrees with you one a statement. When you call `clear` on a vector, it will not change the capacity of the vector and in effect not release the memory. `vector::clear - Erases all of the elements. (For most STL implementations this is O(n) time and does not reduce capacity) `    http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_(C%2B%2B)#Overview_of_functions

Comment: Actual "memory management" is supposed to be abstracted away by `std::vector`. What's important is that after `clear` the objects are destroyed and the memory is, well... Not released as in *"operator delete"*, but released as in *"it's now available to be reused by new objects in the vector or returned to the operating system"*, which is whas I tried to say here- indeed imprecisely.

Comment: Wikipedia is right, but unclear. It is _definitely not_ returned to the OS. We know this because `capacity` does not change (i.e. is not allowed to)

Comment: It's true that destructors are called, though, so in this case of a `vector<vector<T> >`, presumably some memory will be released (in the sense that the destructed vectors will call `std::allocator::deallocate`, which may or may not call `::operator delete`, which in turn may or may not release memory to the OS).